# Error in rowSums(tbl.external.all) : 'x' must be numeric

Tags: r, statistics, bioinformatics, genetics

I try to run SKAT derived R tool, but get stuck with some bug in it.
When running almost last step of the script

```
re<-iECAT.SSD.All(EC.INFO, obj=obj, method="optimal")
```

I get following error:

```
Error in rowSums(tbl.external.all) : 'x' must be numeric
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Error to run iECAT for 1:1918090: Error in rowSums(tbl.external.all) : 'x' must be numeric

2: In if (class(try1) != "try-error") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: No polymorphic SNPs!
4: In if (class(try1) != "try-error") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Previous functions and object assignements went without issues.
Here are the command lines I ran in my R script:

```
library(SKAT)
library(MetaSKAT)
library(iECAT)
File.Bed<-"file.bed"
File.Bim<-"file.bim"
File.Fam<-"fam_all.fam"
File.SetID<-"file.setID"
File.EC<-("file.txt")
File.SSD<-"file.SSD"
File.Info<-"file.SSD.INFO"
File.EC.Info<-"file.SSD.ECINFO"
FAM<-Read_Plink_FAM(File.Fam, Is.binary=TRUE)
Generate_SSD_SetID_wEC(File.Bed, File.Bim, File.Fam, File.SetID, File.EC, File.SSD, File.Info, File.EC.Info)

EC.INFO= Open_SSD_wEC(File.SSD, File.Info, File.EC.Info)

obj<-SKAT_Null_Model(Phenotype ~ 1, out_type="D", data=FAM)
re<-iECAT.SSD.All(EC.INFO, obj=obj, method="optimal") #here error occurs
re
```

fragments of my input files:
bim:

```
1       rs201219564     0       69270   A       G
1       rs2691305       0       69511   A       G
1       rs200505207     0       69761   A       T
1       rs200676709     0       69897   T       C
```

fam:

```
1       1        0 0 1 2
2       2        0 0 1 2
3       3        0 0 1 2
```

setID:

```
set1_183937        rs1169172101
set1_601436        rs373360530
set1_601667        rs879812396
set1_609407        rs61769279
set1_611317        rs12025928
set1_923421        rs7418179
```

EC

```
1       69183   rs1333310753    C       T       0       498
1       69200   rs1453226491    T       C       0       496
1       69208   rs1570409667    A       C       0       478
1       69335   rs773188222     G       A       0       1066
1       69404   rs1328728149    T       C       0       1486
1       69428   rs140739101     T       G       20      1652
1       69438   rs758790416     T       C       0       1768
1       69440   rs1424058787    T       G       0       1766
1       69448   rs1366217262    T       A       0       1828
1       69462   rs1217994907    C       G       0       1870
```

I tried to play around setID file, changing it to:

```
1:183937        rs1169172101
1:601436        rs373360530
1:601667        rs879812396
```

but the issue persisted.
I tried to find issue at suspicious function, but did not see anything:

```
 > print(rowSums)
    new("standardGeneric", .Data = function (x, na.rm = FALSE, dims = 1,
        ...)
    standardGeneric("rowSums"), generic = "rowSums", package = "base",
        group = list(), valueClass = character(0), signature = "x",
        default = new("derivedDefaultMethod", .Data = function (x,
            na.rm = FALSE, dims = 1, ...)
        base::rowSums(x, na.rm = na.rm, dims = dims, ...), target = new("signature",
            .Data = "ANY", names = "x", package = "methods"), defined = new("signature",
            .Data = "ANY", names = "x", package = "methods"), generic = "rowSums"),
        skeleton = (new("derivedDefaultMethod", .Data = function (x,
            na.rm = FALSE, dims = 1, ...)
        base::rowSums(x, na.rm = na.rm, dims = dims, ...), target = new("signature",
            .Data = "ANY", names = "x", package = "methods"), defined = new("signature",
            .Data = "ANY", names = "x", package = "methods"), generic = "rowSums"))(x,
            na.rm, dims, ...))
    <bytecode: 0x399c868>
    <environment: 0x39a4718>
    attr(,"generic")
    [1] "rowSums"
    attr(,"generic")attr(,"package")
    [1] "base"
    attr(,"package")
    [1] "base"
    attr(,"group")
    list()
    attr(,"valueClass")
    character(0)
    attr(,"signature")
    [1] "x"
    attr(,"default")
    Method Definition (Class "derivedDefaultMethod"):
    
    function (x, na.rm = FALSE, dims = 1, ...)
    base::rowSums(x, na.rm = na.rm, dims = dims, ...)
    <environment: 0x301fa08>
    
    Signatures:
            x
    target  "ANY"
    defined "ANY"
    attr(,"skeleton")
    (new("derivedDefaultMethod", .Data = function (x, na.rm = FALSE,
        dims = 1, ...)
    base::rowSums(x, na.rm = na.rm, dims = dims, ...), target = new("signature",
        .Data = "ANY", names = "x", package = "methods"), defined = new("signature",
        .Data = "ANY", names = "x", package = "methods"), generic = "rowSums"))(x,
        na.rm, dims, ...)
    attr(,"class")
    [1] "standardGeneric"
    attr(,"class")attr(,"package")
    [1] "methods"
```

Thank you in advance!